# Updating fstab with sed and a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I am busy writing a bash script to automate the creation of storage; however, I seem to be having major issues updating the `fstab` with the `sed` command.

Once I format the storage, I get the uuid and assign it to a variable which I want to use with sed:

```
blkuuid=$'blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdc'
sed -i '$ a\UUID=''$blkuuid' /mnt/data xfs defaults,nofail 0 99' /etc/fstab
```

I got this to work once but I have no idea what I did. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Use double quotes; single quotes would prevent variable expansion.  (Refer to the linked question for more.)

Comment: Use the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) to look up the difference between ANSI C quoting `$'…'` and command substitution `$(…)`, and the difference between single quotes and double quotes.  You appear to have an unbalanced single quote in the second command line; maybe the one after `$blkuuid` is the interloper.